# Trouble getting types to match up in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I am trying to get a list of the digits from a number, here is my code:

```
digits x = if x > 0 then (i : digits (floor (x / 10))) else [i]
    where i = (mod x 10)
```

The error I get for this code is:

```
No instance for (Integral a0) arising from a use of ‘it’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
    In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `div` instead of `/` and `floor`

Comment: ``digits x = if x > 0 then (x `mod` 10) : digits (x `div` 10) else [x `mod` 10]`` - please note that you will get a reversed list (and an unwanted `0` in most cases)

Comment: That's a GHCi error message from trying to _use_ the function in some context. Always add type signatures to your functions, so the problems become apparent right away, not somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks! the reversed list is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on Carsten's comment, the problem is that Haskell infers the type signature

```
digits :: (RealFrac a, Integral a) => a -> [a]
```

when what you wanted was

```
digits :: Integral a => a -> [a]
```

The reason it infers the former is that you use [`(/)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-) and [`floor`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:floor), which are defined in the `Fractional` and `RealFrac` classes. As leftaroundabout points out, this isn't really a problem until you try to run your function with an actual number, at which point Haskell fails to find a good number type to default to (Haskell number literals are actually polymorphic, and there are special defaulting rules for when you don't explicitly declare a type), hence the weird error message. You would get a more descriptive error message if you tried something like `digits (1 :: Int)`:

```
<interactive>:19:1: error:
  • No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of ‘digits’
  • In the expression: digits (1 :: Int)
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = digits (1 :: Int)
```

The fix, as Carsten pointed out, is to use `div` instead of `(/)` and `floor`.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation

Comment: good answer - I think we should probably include something like this in either the Haskell-tag or in the (beta?) documentation thing StackExchange is working on as this question/problem (using `(/)` where `div` is needed) is really a common issue here - sadly I could not find one of the other occurrences to link this too (as usually the title does not indicate the problem directly)

Comment: @Carsten Where would you recommend putting it in there? I poked around a bit but I couldn't really find a place for this sort of thing...

Comment: in the tag or in the docu? Probably something titled `div vs /`